# Angular not embedding all scripts when build

Tags: javascript, angular, build

I have an angular App that uses a library  to render a draggable tree. It means that I can drag and drop the nodes in the same tree. https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/drag-drop

The integration is pretty simple and it works fine when starting the App locally with ng serve.

However, when I deploy the App on my server using the file generated in the dist folder, the tree displays fine, but the drag and drop doesn't work. It seems that some scripts are missing. No error given in the console.

All the scripts are added to the html index file such as:

- runtime.js
- polyfills.js
- styles.js
- main.js
- vendor.js

What can I check what is missing ?

Comment: make sure you followed these installation steps from DOCS https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/

Comment: Of course I did, it's working but  the dnd is not after deployment

Comment: You can generate prod build and test it locally using angular-http-server npm module